# cassandra Internode transport protocol

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I am trying to understand how Cassandra serializes data and transports them between nodes.

- I'd like to know the protocol (Protocol buffer? MessagePack?, Custom?) that is being used to transport data between nodes in a cluster.
- My current understand is that CQL is used for client-server communication. Is this also true for server to server communication?

Comment: [Did you do any research](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureGossipAbout_c.html)?

Comment: That link talks about the Gossip protocol. What I want to know is whether cassandra adds data to be replicated within the gossip messages.